# How to use kendo-ui in an existing angularjs project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

I'm super new to AngularJS. I'm trying to use Kendo-ui-core in my project. I'm using Yeoman, grunt, node & bower.

I've downloaded the pre-configured zip package for kendo-ui-core from http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui/open-source-core

I've added these to the .html

```
<link href="styles/kendo-styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="styles/kendo-styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="scripts/kendo-scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/kendo-scripts/kendo.core.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/kendo-scripts/kendo.angular.min.js"></script>
```

Also in the body

```
<label>Birthday: <input kendo-date-picker /></label>
```

and in the app.js, I've added a dependency for "kendo.directives"

```
angular.module('myApp', [ 'kendo.directives',
'ngAnimate',
'ngCookies',
'ngResource',
'ngRoute',
'ngSanitize',
'ngTouch',
'restangular',
'ngDialog',
'bgDirectives'])
```

The problem is I got no error but I got also nothing !!! Just the normal input tag

Any idea what I'm missing here ?!! what's wrong with it ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working now :)

I've used to the scripts from Kendo CDN as mentioned here: https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/#using-kendo-ui-core-via-the-kendo-static-cdn

```
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script> 
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/js/kendo.ui.core.min.js"></script>
```

instead of those from the pre-configured zip package downloaded.

**or if you are using bower**, so just use "bower install kendo-ui-core -save" as mentioned here: https://github.com/kendo-labs/bower-kendo-ui#about-kendo-ui-core  and then the scripts includes from CDN (mentioned above) are even not needed anymore, so just remove them, because everything will be managed by bower so they will be installed and included.